# Definition of Polynomials in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, notation

Consider the following definitions

[image: Definition of polynomial function]

[image: Definition of plugging a linear operator into the polynomial]

where $\bf{F}$ is the real or complex number field and $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the vector space of all linear operators on $V$.

I think that the notation $p(T)$ does not make sense as $T$ is not in the domain of $p$.

Am I right? If *YES*, So what is the right notation for this?

Comment: The image seems to be a definition of $p(T)$. That is, it's supposed to be defining something previously undefined.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: $p$ is denoted to be a polynomial function from $\bf{F}$ to $\bf{F}$. So it seems the notation for the new definition conflicts with the previous one!

Comment: @H.R.: Do you worry about the fact that you use the same notation $+$ for addition of integers as you do for real numbers, complex numbers, vectors, polynomials, elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, etc.?

Comment: @H.R. This is quite standard I believe. Consider this example where we overload the distance function: Let $d: X\times X \to [0,+\infty)$ denote the distance function. Then if $C$ is a subset of $X$ and $x\in X$ we define $d(x,C) := \min_c \{ d(x, c) \mid c\in C\}$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Ah! :D you are right. In fact, I really always wonder why they use the same notation for all of them! Usually, I use subscripts for addition in different algebraic structures for myself! :)

Comment: This is standard notation.  This article might provide some context and explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus

Comment: @mathematician: Thanks. The link was helpful. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The notation is very common. If one is very strict one could see a problem, **but** I would say the main issue is at saying "$\mathcal{P}({\bf{F}})$ is the vector space of all polynomials from $\bf{F}$ to $\bf{F}$." Instead it is "the vector space of all polynomials over $\bf{F}$" or "with coefficients from $\bf{F}$."

A polynomial is an object in its own right.

The polynomial $P$ then gives rise to a map from  $\bf{F}$ to  $\bf{F}$ that is usually also denoted by $P$.

*In the same way*  the polynomial $P$  gives rise to a map from  $\mathcal{L}(V)$ to  $\mathcal{L}(V)$ that is usually also denoted by $P$.

It is true that very strictly the polynomial and the maps it induces are different objects, but usually one does not distinguish those notationally.

Let me add that if you really insist that "$\mathcal{P}({\bf{F}})$ is the vector space of all polynomial [maps] from $\bf{F}$ to $\bf{F}$" then indeed there would be a problem. But I doubt that is actually what is done in your source, and if it were done then this would be the main problem.

Well, turns out this is done. In this way, the definition is not really coherent. The *main* problem is that the coefficients $a_i$ are not necessarily uniquely determined by the map $P$ from $F$ to $F$ and thus $P(T)$ is not well-defined (different choices of $a_i$ yielding the same function from $F$ to $F$ will yield different results for $P(T)$).

However, this is only an actual problem if the field is finite. If the field is infinite such as the reals or the complex numbers, than a polynomial map uniquely (up to spurious $0$ coefficients) determines the coefficients.

So that to each polynomial function one has a tuple of coefficients and then one defines $P(T)$ as it is defined. (Michael Hardy makes a very good point there.)

Either way, there is no problem to consider a polynomial as a formal expressions to begin with $a_0X^0+ a_1 X^1 + \dots + a_n X^n$. To define it as a function and then retrieve the coefficients is not my preferred way, but I can see why somebody might want to take it.

Comment: I corrected it in the question! In the text, polynomial functions are simply called polynomials. :)

Comment: What precisely is written in the text? This is important. If it really polynomials are  polynomial functions and the field can be finite the definition you recall just makes no sense. (Irrespective of the naming.)

Comment: I added the original definition of $\mathcal{P}(F)$ in text to the question. Please take a look

Comment: Thanks. That's surprising. Then you are right that this is not presented well.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the attention and (+1) One thing I noted is that in analysis we have the same problem. For example for a function $f: D \to \Bbb{R}$, we denote the set of all values of $f$ (range of $f$) by $f(D)$. It is similar to this issue. Right?

Comment: In the book, it is proved that the coefficients are unique when $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{C}$. :)

Comment: Yes, it is simlilar. A map $f:D \to R$ induces a map from the subsets of $D$ to the subsets of $R$, via $f(A) =  \{f(a) \colon a \in A \}$. If one wants to be strict one might introduce a new letter for this or call it $\hat{f}$ or something. But usually it is more convenient to allow reuse of notation if there is no risk of confusion. It might be interesting to note that in programming  different programming languages approach the issue differently. Some are very strict regarding the type of the argument, others will adapt what they do based on the type of the argument.

Comment: Yes, if the field is infinite then the coeffcients are unique and there is no real problem. I will make one more addition to the answer.

Comment: Nice point about programming! :) I now recognized that *Maple* and *Mathematica* decide to see what is the type of the input first! I think it is sort of reasonable! :) For example in *Mathematica* the function $D[]$ which takes the derivatives can have different input types such as functions or lists!

Answer (score 11):

Polynomials have their own **independent** existence - they are **not** inherently functions from $\mathbf{F}$ to $\mathbf{F}$ or functions at all for that matter.

For example, over the finite field $\mathbf{F}=\mathbb{F}_p$, the polynomial $z^p-z\in\mathbb{F}_p[z]$ evaluates to $0$ for any element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ that you plug in, but it is extremely, importantly, different than the zero polynomial $0\in\mathbb{F}_p[z]$.

In general, if $p$ is an element of the ring of polynomials $\mathbf{F}[z]$,  the notation $p(\theta)$ is explained like this:

- there is an $\mathbf{F}$-algebra $R$ (sometimes left implicit) containing the element $\theta$
- there is a unique $\mathbf{F}$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbf{F}[z]\to R$ with the property that $\varphi(z)=\theta$
- the notation $p(\theta)$ refers to the element of $R$ that is the image of $p$ under that homomorphism $\varphi$

To evaluate a polynomial at an element of $\mathbf{F}$, you have $R=\mathbf{F}$.

In the definition you're citing, you have $R=\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that the second expression does not make sense because $T$ is not in the domain of $p$ is precisely the reason why this definition is given.

Of course, the judgment that it does not make sense stems from our currently conventional ways of reasoning about mathematics, which will further evolve over time, just as our current modes of reasoning are not the same as those that Euler used.

Comment: So, in some sense we are extending the definition of the map $p$. :) Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @H.R. : I'm not sure it's really an extension as much as a definition of a naturally corresponding map on a different domain. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, your definition of a polynomial is broken. Here's a better one:

> **Definition.** A polynomial (in the variable $x$) with coefficients in $R$ is an element of the $R$-algebra freely generated by the set $\{x\}$. This is usually written $R[x]$.

Okay. There's an evaluation map $$E:R[x]  \times R \rightarrow R$$ defined as follows: we assume $E$ is a morphism of $R$-algebras in the first argument, and that $E(x,a) = a$. For example: $$E(x^2+x,5) = E(x,5)^2+E(x,5) = 5^2+5 = 30$$

Instead of $E(P,a)$, we usually write $P(a)$. The above argument becomes $$(x^2+x)(5) = x(5)^2+x(5) = 5^2+5 = 30.$$

Actually I prefer the notation $(x:=a)P$. The above argument becomes:

$$(x:=5)(x^2+x) = ((x:=5)x)^2+(x:=5)x = 5^2+5 = 30$$

The nice thing about $(x:=5)$ is that it generalizes to the multivariable case with less fuss. Its also a little cleaner to define: its the unique $R$-algebra morphism $$(x:=a) : R[x] \rightarrow R$$ satisfying $(x:=a)x = a.$

This defines a map $$R \rightarrow (R[x] \rightarrow R),$$ which can of course be made into to a map $$R[x] \times R \rightarrow R,$$ namely $E$, so the two approaches are equivalent.

Alright. What about linear operators? Let $V$ denote an $R$-module. Then $\mathrm{End}(V)$ can be viewed as an $R$-algebra, assuming $R$ is commutative. By the way, it needn't be a ring; everything I'm saying here generalizes to semirings w/o further comment. Anyway, by the universal property of $R[x]$, we can assign to each $f \in \mathrm{End}(V)$ an $R$-algebra morphism $$(x:=f) : R[x] \rightarrow \mathrm{End}(V)$$ by asserting that $(x:=f)x = f$.

This defines a map $$\mathrm{End}(V) \rightarrow (R[x] \rightarrow \mathrm{End}(V)).$$

Instead of $(x:= f)P$, you may prefer to write $P(f)$, of course.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the main issue. -1 for drowning it in lots of unnecessary algebra that makes everything more confusing for the OP. Seriously, freely generated R-algebras?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, how do you propose to define evaluation if not by the universal property?

Comment: I am not sure if you are trolling me or not, but I'll answer anyway. "The evaluation of the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i x^i \in R[x]$ at point $y \in R$ is $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i y^i$" seems a perfectly reasonable definition to me.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, that works. But, you might want to assume that $a_d$ is non-zero, so that well-definedness of that map is obvious. I think you also need to deal with $0$ separately, since we're assuming $a_0 \neq 0$ for the $d=0$ case. Its more complicated in the two variable case, of course. Using my approach, the two variable case is easy. Let $A$ denote an $R$-algebra. Then given $x_0,y_0 \in A$, we define $(x:=x_0,y:=y_0) : R[x,y] \rightarrow A$ by assuming that its an $R$-algebra homomorphism satisfying $$(x:=x_0,y:=y_0)x = x_0 \qquad (x:=x_0,y:=y_0)y = y_0.$$ How easy is that?